# Popular checkbox com jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, checkbox

Preciso popular o `input` com dados vindo do *jQuery*.

Tenho o seguinte `input`:

```
 <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="turmas"/>
</label>
```

No *jQuery* tenho o seguinte código:

```
    var turma= JSON.parse(data); 
    $.each(turma, function() {
       count++;
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {   
      $('<input>').val(turma['turma'][i]).text(turma['turma'][i]).appendTo('#turmas'); 
    }
```

Estrutura do *JSON*:

```
{"Turma A", "Turma B"}
```

Troquei o `<input>` por `<label>` e ele mostra as turmas, mas não mostra os *checkboxes*.

Comment: Larissa, tem pouco código aí! Não dá pra rodar/simular seu código. Você quer popular com dados vindos via ajax ou diretamente na renderização que, no caso, está fazendo com o PHP? Poste o restante do código...

Comment: Não é recomendado utilizar o comentário para implementar sua pergunta. Para tal, [edite sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/356956/edit) e adicione as informações que quer complementar. Lembre-se destas informações que mencionei.

Comment: os dados vem em forma de array por ajax

Comment: Qual a estrutura desse JSON? Onde você quer "encaixar" os checkboxes? Dentro da `label`? No seu script ele vai pra dentro do input. Tá errado! Veja: [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) / Outra coisa, já fez um [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)? Outra leitura recomendada: [Perguntanto - central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: [Edite a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/356956/edit), coração!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para começar, veja isto:

> estrutura do json: {"Turma A", "Turma B"}

Seu *JSON* segue uma sintaxe errada! Veja:

[image: jsonlint.com]

> Teste seus JSONs com o [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)!

Uma rápida explicação:

1. `{}` (chaves) para objetos. Logo, precisa informar a propriedade:

   ```
   { "nome" : "LipESprY" }
   ```
2. `[]` (colchetes) para vetores (lista). Logo, não declaramos a propriedade:

   ```
   ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"]
   ```
3. Se temos mais de um objeto, aí devemos colocá-los dentro de um vetor (lista):

   ```
   [{
       "nome": "LipESprY"
   }, {
       "nome": "Larissa"
   }]
   ```

Seu JSON corrigido, fica assim:

```
["Turma A", "Turma B"]
```

Obviamente que você pode melhorar, e muito, seu JSON. Mas não é o objetivo da minha resposta "melhorar" aquilo que não se refere ao problema. Só mencionei este problema devido a necessidade de corrigi-lo.

---

Agora para popular os dados, pode fazer assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Popular checkbox por LipESprY</title>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label id="lb_checkbox">
        </label>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        data = JSON.parse('["Turma A", "Turma B"]');

        for (let valor of data) {
            $("<input type='checkbox' value='"+valor+"'>"+valor+"<br>").appendTo('#lb_checkbox');
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

> Foi o que pude desenvolver com o pouco de código que você postou, depois de bastante esforço! Agora cabe a você adaptar ao seu projeto...